# Issue with local-exec and passing values into it

Tags: terraform

I'm having an issue passing string values into my local-exec resource within Terraform.

Here is the local-exec that I'm provisioning:

```
resource "null_resource" "sftp_server_update" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOF
    aws transfer update-server --server-id ${aws_transfer_server.aws_transfer_service.id} --endpoint-details 
      AddressAllocationIds= ${toset(aws_eip.sftp.*.public_ip)}, \
      SubnetIds= ${toset(var.subnet_ids)}, \
      VPCEndpointID= ${aws_vpc_endpoint.sftp.id}, \
      VpcId= ${var.vpc_id}, \
    --endpoint-type VPC --identity-provider SERVICE_MANAGED --logging-role ${aws_iam_role.aws_transfer_role.arn} --protocols SFTP /
    --profile ${var.account} --region ${var.region}
    EOF
  }
  depends_on = [
    null_resource.sftp_server_off
  ]
}
```

I think it may have to do with the aws_eip resource or the subnet_ids variable so here is the code block for those:

aws_eip:

```
resource "aws_eip" "sftp" {
  count = 3

  vpc = true
}
```

subnet_ids variable:

```
subnet_ids = ["subnet-id1","subnet-id2","subnet-id3"]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why aren't you using the `aws_transfer_server` resource?

Comment: Because the aws_transfer_server doesn't have the VPC option yet. Only PUBLIC and VPC_ENDPOINT.

Answer (score 0):

A bit more info on what exactly your "issue" is would be helpful, but right off the bat, this line

```
   --endpoint-type VPC --identity-provider SERVICE_MANAGED --logging-role ${aws_iam_role.aws_transfer_role.arn} --protocols SFTP /
```

uses '/' instead of '\' for continuation.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use a combination of `join` and `toset` for `AllocationIds` and just `join` for `SubnetIds`. Try below:

```
resource "null_resource" "sftp_server_update" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOF
    aws transfer update-server --server-id ${aws_transfer_server.aws_transfer_service.id} --endpoint-details AddressAllocationIds="${join("\", \"", toset(aws_eip.sftp.*.id))}", SubnetIds="${join("\", \"", var.subnet_ids)}", VPCEndpointID= ${aws_vpc_endpoint.sftp.id}, VpcId= ${var.vpc_id}, --endpoint-type VPC --identity-provider SERVICE_MANAGED --logging-role ${aws_iam_role.aws_transfer_role.arn} --protocols SFTP --profile ${var.account} --region ${var.region}
    EOF
  }
  depends_on = [
    null_resource.sftp_server_off
  ]
}
```